# How to get instance of ECSlidingViewController in another storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uistoryboard, ecslidingviewcontroller

**Little Background** :-
I have two storyboards in my project (one with autolayout and one without autolayout). `'Main'` storyboard contains `ECSlidingViewController` where I set `topviewcontroller` as mentioned on the `ECSliding` github page like below:-

**My Code**:-

```
 -(void)GoToNewStoryBoard
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboardWithAutolayout = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AutolayoutBoard" bundle:nil];

    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboardWithAutolayout instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerinNewStoryBoard"];
}

-(void)someMethodInNewViewController
{
    ECSlidingViewController *sliding_viewController = (ECSlidingViewController*)[self.navigationController visibleViewController];
    if([sliding_viewController isKindOfClass:[ECSlidingViewController class]])
    {
        MenuViewController *menu = (MenuViewController *)sliding_viewController.underLeftViewController;
        NSString *windowType = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKeyPath:@"menuWindowType"];
        if([windowType isEqualToString:@"Push_PaymentPage"])
        {
            [menu pushToViewController];
        }
    }
}



-(void)pushToViewControllerInNewStoryBoard
{
    self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewVCNav"];

    [self.slidingViewController resetTopViewAnimated:YES];    
}
```

**Problem**:-

How do I get the instance of `ECSlidingViewController` in View controller class in new storyboard as `[self.navigationController visibleViewController]` gives me instance of `UIViewController` class instead of `ECSlidingViewController`.

Comment: you can access that reference  from `appDelegate`.

Comment: @NimitParekh How do i do that ?

Comment: all the code is there above in question

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the object into `AppDelegate.m` file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

     UIStoryboard *storyboardWithAutolayout = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"AutolayoutBoard" bundle:nil];
     self.slidingViewController = = (ECSlidingViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                 instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ECSlidingVctrID"];
     self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboardWithAutolayout instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerinNewStoryBoard"];
 return YES;
}
```

Create one more method into the `AppDelegate.m` file.

```
-(void)changeViewControllerIntoSlider:(UIViewController*)vc{
     self.slidingViewController.topViewController = [storyboardWithAutolayout instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerinNewStoryBoard"];
}
```

Now you can access those method and object of `ECSlidingViewController`.

Import AppDelegate file into your controller.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

Then Access appDelegate Object.
AppDelegate appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

```
[appDel slidingViewController]//Now you got the reference of slider you can do any thing.
```

Then Access appDelegate method.

```
AppDelegate appDel = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[appDel changeViewControllerIntoSlider:"Your view controller according storyboard"]
```

Comment: Thanks Nimit this Approach seems to be fine. However i manage redirection logic in class MenuViewController which is also underLeftViewController

Comment: @AshishPisey for that need the sample project so getting much more idea

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `[self.navigationController visibleViewController]` i used `self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController` as follows:-

```
-(void)someMethodInNewViewController
{ 
    MenuViewController *menu = (MenuViewController*) self.slidingViewController.underLeftViewController;

    [menu pushToAcceptedMember];
}
```

This gave me the `ECSlidingViewController` instance.